# Cannot render multiple AugmnentedImage nodes in ARCore

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I want to render different `AugmentedImage` nodes on SceneView by scanning the reference  images using ARCore. The nodes are perfectly being rendered on first scan, but after then if I scan other images, they get into tracking state but couldn't render.

```
if (!augmentedImageMap.containsKey(currentAugmentedImage)){
    AugmentedImageNode node = new AugmentedImageNode(this,currentAugmentedImage);
    augmentedImageMap.put(currentAugmentedImage, node);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(node);
}
```

Also I tried `node.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene())`
but results are the same.
The code is same for rendering the nodes, but I'm wondering why only the first node gets rendered?